# PouchDB sync performance

Tags: pouchdb

---------------- My original question below was because I had a large memory consumption on my mobile app when triggering a sync --------------

Regarding performance is it favorable to have a special document that says whether or not a sync is needed and do a replication only on this document. For example having the following doc :

```
{ 
  _id: replication,
  replication_needed: true
}
```

And then trigger replication

```
let rep = PouchDB.replicate(source, target, { live: true, doc_ids: ['replication'] })
.on('complete', function (info) {
  // If doc.replication == true then do a complete sync here
}
```

Or is pouchdb/couchdb already optimized for this? I am wondering if on large database it does not take time to look for every document change?

Below is a screenshot of the performance tab in chrome when triggering a sync 
[image: In performance tab here are all the requests done when a sync (with no doc update) is done]

Comment: Such a document would be worthless in most scenarios, since there's no way to know locally if a sync is needed, since sync is bi-directional.  But for a detailed answer to your question, you can see exactly how the CouchDB replication protocol determines what should be sycned by [reading the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/protocol.html).

Comment: But yes I do know because every time my app is making a document change I can write to this particular doc that a change has been done. Then I have a continuous bi-directional replication only on this particular doc to know if a sync is needed.

Comment: Thank you @Flimzy for the doc, it is very well explained !

Comment: That approach won't work, either, because you'll have two (or more) systems updating the same doc.

Comment: Alright I was missing the big picture ! I was oversimplifying the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The sync protocol was not the source of my problem. Thanks to @Flimzy I should have read the doc which explains in depth the protocol : http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/protocol.html

For those maybe who will encounter a problem concerning performance with pouchDB sync (it was my situation, my app was freezing on sync with a database containing less than 100 docs making me wondering if sync was efficient), the problem was because I had attachments in some docs (not even large one but few pictures and videos) and it seems to be a problem for replication in couchdb.

Note that I have a website with thousand of pictures and video and it works well but it does not use live synchronization.

I tested without attachment on my mobile app and the sync is done very smoothly with 20 000 docs (db over 50mb). So just handle media file another way if you need live sync.